# Update parent object from child object

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

I have one parent object that is group and another child object that is individual. I have to concatenate two field individual name and designation of child object and update parent object field that is description using after trigger. I fail in this.

I tried but not work

Comment: show the code you've written so far, even if it doesn't compile.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.